# Intersection in the Hausdorff metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d)$ be complete metric space, and denote by $H(Y,d)$ the Hausdorff metric space on the compact subsets of $(Y,d)$.  Let 
$$
f,g:(X,d)\rightarrow H(y,d),
$$
be continuous maps (may be assumed to be $\epsilon$-Lipschitz, for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ if necessary).  Then define the function $h$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
h: &(X,d) \rightarrow H(y,d)\\
h&(x)\to f(x)\cap g(x);
\end{aligned}
$$
assume that $h(x)\neq \emptyset$ for every $x \in X$.

Then must $h$ be continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let X=Y=[0,1], and d be the Euclidean metric.  Let f(x)={0,x} and g(x)={0,1-x}, then f and g are continuous.  h(x) is not empty for all x in X,  consider a sequence converges to 1/2, h is not contiunous at 1/2.